# Rename Tool for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

I have a database that had 15 years of cruft stuffed into it by multiple teams and people in multiple languages.  I am looking to rename tables/columns/constraints to match some type of a standard.

The problem is that a column may be referenced in a ton of stored procs and there is no way to find other than search each sproc with a tool like SQL Digger.  The problem is that I want to rename a massive amount of entities and doing it manually for each sounds painful.

I've been looking for a tool that helps in name refactoring and can't find anything.  Some tools [here] vaguely claim to do that, but don't really (I haven't looked at all the ones listed to be fair).

Has anyone had experience with such a tool?

Comment: See this book:
http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Databases-Evolutionary-Database-Design/dp/0321293533
It's still not easy, but the book has some worthwhile techniques.

Comment: From [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/):  `SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('YourObject', 'OBJECT');
GO`

Comment: Just be aware that dependency support has changed over the past few versions, and I don't think sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities was available before SQL Server 2008. Also that particular DMV doesn't really seem to help with column names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used database projects (in Visual Studio 2010) for  refactoring activities in the past with a good deal of success. Database projects definitely have a number of quirks but nothing you can't work around.

You can find more details about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193420

Comment: Wow, had no idea this existed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx) for some time. It is a freeware tool and so far it works very well.

There's an article ["How to change an object name without breaking your SQL database"](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/2012/12/how-to-change-object-name-without.html) in their solution center.

I've noticed a new version announcement (2013), however I am not sure if it will remain free or not.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when updating objects using any of the tools mentioned above because they only search for references in you database. Important thing to keep in mind is the code you have in data access layers of your applications.

Another tool you might want to check out is [ApexSQL Clean](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_clean.aspx). It can find all unused database objects, show all references visually but it also searches for .NET solutions and finds references there.

Again, considering that your database is 15 years old you probably have code in different legacy applications and not only .NET. Anyway, good luck. Hope this is all done by now :)

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this, but have used other of their Sql Server tools, and they did what they claimed.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

[SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) ([review here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/357905/Evaluating-SQL-Server-Data-Tools))

Red-Gate SQL Refactor (well, now part of [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/))

Note that these tools can only be smart enough to find references that are exposed through direct reference or through proper dependencies. If you construct a table or column name using dynamic SQL, you're out of luck.

I also blogged about keeping sysdepends up to date a few years ago, however I'm not sure how useful it will be with columns in particular:

https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008